# How to add css and js to a views-view-table--viewname.tpl.php

Tags: 7

I am theming a  particular view "test" so my theme file is "views-view-table--test.tpl.php".
Its working fine.

I want to add css and javascript to the "views-view-table--test.tpl.php" file
Used the below code to add css and javascript. but its not working:

```
drupal_add_css("themes/bartik/style-test.css", $type = 'file', $media = 'all', $preprocess = FALSE);
drupal_add_js("jquery.min.js", $type = 'file', $media = 'all', $preprocess = FALSE);
```

How to add css and js to views-view-table--viewname.tpl.php file.

Comment: Are you putting that code in the template?

Comment: @Alex Gill: I am putting this code in views-view-table--test.tpl.php file. I have place this file in folder themes/barthik/views/views-view-table--test.tpl.php

Comment: See answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by using a process function at theme level...

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
    if (isset($vars['view']->name) && $vars['view']->name == 'YOURVIEW') {
        drupal_add_css("themes/bartik/style-test.css", $type = 'file', $media = 'all', $preprocess = FALSE);
        drupal_add_js("jquery.min.js", $type = 'file', $media = 'all', $preprocess = FALSE); 
    }
}
```

1. Change 'YOURTHEME' to the theme you are using so if 'bartik' then
   you want bartik_preprocess_views_view().
2. Change 'YOURVIEW' to the name of your view. You can get this by
   printing $vars['view']->name from the function.
3. Clear caches after adding function.

Comment: I have added this code to bartik template.php file. But its css and js files are not loading in my view page

Comment: See updated answer...

Comment: Did the things mentioned by you while placing the code itself. But not working

Comment: Mentioned the wrong css path. Thanks its working now.